# Python program to get the top three values from a python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to get the top 3 values from a python dictionary. I wrote the following code where the key's are numbers and it works.

```
sample = {1 : 45, 2 :35, 3 : 41, 4 :55, 5: 24}


cnt=0
for key in sample.items():
    cnt=cnt+1


for i in range (1,cnt):
    for j in range(i+1,cnt):
        if (sample[i]>sample[j]):
            pass
        elif(sample[i]<sample[j]):
            temp=sample[i]
            sample[i]=sample[j]
            sample[j]=temp


j=0
for key,value in sample.items():
    if(j<3):
        print(key,value)
        j=j+1
    else:
        break
```

How would I go ahead with this if the key's are strings, when the dictionary is

```
sample={'item1': 45, 'item2':35, 'item3': 41, 'item4':55, 'item5': 24}
```

I understand sorting each like this:
 `sample['item1']>sample['item2']` and so on would be really inefficient.
Thanks!

Comment: Why would sorting strings be really inefficient? But given your format you can just use `Counter(sample).most_common(3)`.

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate as Author is looking for some solution without using inbuilt functions. Just using for loop and conditional statements

Comment: Yes I would like to solve it without using inbuilt functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` function:

```
topn = 3

# ascending
dict(sorted(sample.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])[:topn])

{'item1': 45, 'item2': 35, 'item3': 41}

# descending
dict(sorted(sample.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)[:topn])
```

Comment: If I had to solve this without using the 'lambda' function. Would it be able to iterate through them now that the key's are strings using only for loops and condition statements.

Comment: you want to solve this using a for loop?

Comment: Yes, I would like to solve this without using in-built functions